# Comparison of Titan to Europa

Tags: gravity, atmosphere, titan, solar-wind, europa

Why does Titan have an atmosphere denser than that of the Earth?
And why does Europa not have even a fraction of Titans atmosphere given that it is not that small as compared to Titan?

Comment: I don't think this question ought to be closed. This is a valid, single question– the OP wants to know the reason for the anomalous atmospheric density of Titan. Consider it this way: Titan has a dense atmosphere, but why don't other moons?

Comment: Europa is smaller than Titan, 3000 km in diameter versus 5000. But two other Jupiter's moons (Ganimede and Callisto) indeed are of the same size as Titan and have no significant atmosphere.

Comment: Short answer: We don't know. We can't even properly explain the atmospheric masses of Venus, Earth and Mars. And Moons follow their own complicated geological evolutionary paths, modified by the formation environment in their nascent circumplanetary discs, which is another poorly understood factor.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer why is this not an Astronomy SE question?

Comment: @J.Doe I concur. But since it is a [planetary science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_science) question, being quite interdisciplinary, I assume posting it on space.se or astronomy.se is only a matter of choice. Nonetheless, a better response might've been met under the [`planetary-atmosphere`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-atmosphere) tag on astro.se.

Comment: Related [post on Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/how-does-titan-maintain-the-atmosphere).

Answer (score 2):

Following is a block quote from *[How to Get an Atmosphere](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/titan/atmosphere.html)*
by Peter Tyson

> Saturn's moon Titan belongs to a very select club within the solar
>   system. It is one of only four "terrestrial" planets or moons—those
>   with solid bodies, as opposed to those made largely of gas, like
>   Jupiter and Saturn—that has a substantial atmosphere. The other three
>   that wear blankets of gas are Venus, Mars, and our own Earth.
>
> Why just these four? Why not also, say, Mercury, Jupiter's biggest
>   moons, our moon? How did those lucky four come by their atmospheres?
>
> It turns out that getting an atmosphere—and holding on to it—really
>   comes down to how big and how close to the sun you are (or, for Titan,
>   how close you are to a really big planet). For astrophysicists, it's
>   infinitely more complex than that, but if you just want the quick and
>   dirty answer, that's it, and here's why: Original gas
>
> The story of planetary atmospheres begins back at the beginning of our
>   solar system, when the planets were forming. During that period, the
>   so-called inner planets—Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars—all developed
>   the same kind of air, a so-called primary atmosphere. It consisted
>   mostly of hydrogen and helium, the two elements that today make up 98
>   percent of the sun and gas giants like Jupiter.
>
> Like planet-sized magnets, the proto-planets had sufficient gravity to
>   draw these two gaseous elements in from the solar nebula, the vast
>   cloud of gas and dust that surrounded the sun early in the solar
>   system's history. In that primordial time, the sun was not very bright
>   and thus not very hot, and this allowed the four inner planets to hold
>   onto those atmospheres.
>
> Three factors play into a gas's ability to escape the pull of a
>   planet's gravity: temperature, molecular mass, and escape velocity
>   (the speed a molecule needs to achieve to escape into space). Hotter,
>   lighter, and faster particles more easily slip out of a planet's
>   gravitational grip into space than cooler, heavier, and slower
>   particles.
>
> Hydrogen and helium are two of the lightest molecular-weight molecules
>   out there. And as the sun grew brighter and hotter, the molecules of
>   hydrogen and helium that the four inner planets had been able to
>   retain became hotter and faster, finally reaching escape velocity.
>   When that happened, perhaps within a few hundred million years after
>   the formation of the inner planets, these gases escaped into space,
>   leaving Earth and its three companions little more than balls of rock
>   in space.
>
> The four giant outer planets, meanwhile—Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and
>   Neptune—were able to keep their hydrogen and helium because of their
>   size: their gravitational pull is mighty enough to contain those two
>   light gases, and the sun is too far away for its heat to make any
>   difference. So those four gas giants still host their primary
>   atmospheres. Putting on air
>
> Fortunately for us, there are secondary atmospheres, otherwise we
>   wouldn't be here. These are atmospheres that arise long after a
>   planet's primary atmosphere has vanished into the ether. Yet not all
>   rocky bodies have the means to sustain them. (Mercury, for one, is too
>   close to the sun to hold onto any type of gas.) How did the four solid
>   bodies that have them win the atmospheric lottery?
>
> Leaving Titan aside for the moment, Earth, Mars, and Venus all began
>   developing their secondary atmospheres in the same way. Over time
>   their envelopes of air would become as unlike as heaven and hell—in
>   the case of Earth and Venus, for example—but initially they likely
>   appeared largely the same. The reason is that, despite their
>   differences today, these three planets lie in roughly the same
>   neighborhood of the solar system and are thought to consist of roughly
>   the same mix of elementary stuff.
>
> Earth became heavenly, Mars froze solid, and all hell broke loose on
>   Venus. What happened?
>
> While Earth, Mars, and Venus eventually got to the point where they
>   could no longer embrace hydrogen and helium, they did have sufficient
>   gravity and cool enough surface temperatures to retain heavier
>   molecular-weight gases like carbon dioxide and water vapor. And they
>   had plenty of these two substances stored away in one form or another
>   within their stony bodies. The CO2 and H2O came from two sources: the
>   original building blocks out of which the planets formed as well as
>   comets that regularly slammed into the planets early in their history.
>
> Fortunately, again, for us, these crucial substances of CO2 and
>   H2O—and also nitrogen, which comprises 78 percent of our
>   atmosphere—were not irretrievably locked in the rocks. These
>   substances had a catalyst that helped free them: heat. Within each
>   planet, a molten core created during the planet's initial formation
>   released heat, and so did the slow decay of radioactive elements deep
>   beneath the surface. This heat kept each planet toasty enough to
>   produce volcanic eruptions, which spewed these gases out of the
>   interior.
>
> Despite increased warmth from the sun, these heavier molecules could
>   not escape the gravity of Earth, Mars, and Venus, respectively, and so
>   they began building up just above each planet's surface. The result
>   was a secondary atmosphere—or what most of us know simply as the air.
>
> But, in time, Earth became heavenly, Mars froze solid, and all hell
>   broke loose on Venus. What happened? From heaven to hell
>
> This is where the how-close-you-are-to-the-sun part comes in. On
>   Earth, all that water vapor belched out of volcanoes condensed in the
>   young atmosphere into liquid water, then fell to the surface as rain.
>   Over eons, this formed the oceans. Most of the CO2, meanwhile, became
>   incorporated into the seas and into sedimentary rocks. Most, but not
>   all, and this is crucial: enough CO2 remained as gas in the atmosphere
>   to create the greenhouse effect that keeps our planet a
>   life-sustaining average global temperature of about 59°F. Everything
>   eased into a wonderful balance—all brought about by our ideal distance
>   from the sun.
>
> As for Mars, its secondary atmosphere had two strikes against it from
>   the start: the planet's size (too small) and its distance from the sun
>   (too far). In its first 500 million years or so, the Red Planet had a
>   warm atmosphere and liquid-water oceans, just like Earth. But Mars is
>   so small that its internal heat engine burned out early on, and it is
>   so far away from the sun that all the water vapor that its once-active
>   volcanoes had erupted eventually froze out of the atmosphere, becoming
>   trapped beneath the surface as ice. All this left the Red Planet as
>   cold and barren and apparently lifeless as the moon. Mars still has an
>   atmosphere, but its pressure is 100 times less than Earth's and it's
>   almost entirely composed of CO2—about the last thing we'd want to
>   breathe.
>
> Venus has roughly the same concentration of CO2 as Mars, yet its
>   atmosphere went in precisely the opposite direction. Size wasn't an
>   issue: Venus has about the same mass as Earth so is plenty hot within.
>   But distance from the sun has made all the difference. Venus is near
>   enough to our star that all the water vapor released from its
>   volcanoes burned off long ago, and without liquid water, the planet
>   could not form oceans that could absorb the CO2.
>
> The result has been a runaway greenhouse effect. While a greenhouse
>   effect raises the temperature of Mars by about 5°F and Earth by about
>   35°F, on Venus it has jacked up the temperature by around 500°F. The
>   resulting atmosphere is truly nasty from our perspective: hotter than
>   a self-cleaning oven, with a density about 10 percent that of water
>   and a pressure about what you'd feel a half mile down in the ocean. A
>   moon with atmosphere
>
> And what about Titan? Why did it get an atmosphere when, for example,
>   none of Jupiter's big moons, which are a lot closer to the sun, did?
>   Well, in this case, distance from the sun doesn't really come into it;
>   the moons of the outer planets are so far away that it's a moot point.
>   But distance does factor in—distance to a giant planet. And, again,
>   size matters. In fact, a moon needs the right balance of nearness to a
>   giant neighbor and adequate gravity—that is, size—to gain and hold an
>   atmosphere, and of all the moons in the solar system, only on Titan
>   did Nature strike that balance.
>
> Whether we humans could ever severely or permanently alter our own
>   atmosphere is unknown, but do we really want to take that chance?
>
> Titan is close enough to Saturn that it gets squeezed by tidal forces
>   powerful enough to heat up its interior. So the volcanic activity that
>   long ago died out, for instance, on our similarly sized moon, has
>   continued there. That activity releases CO2 and water vapor, but since
>   Titan's mean surface temperature is -289°F, both of those quickly fall
>   out as ice on the surface. That leaves nitrogen, which remains a gas
>   at that temperature, and methane, which builds up in an interaction
>   between sunlight and CO2 ice. The result is an atmosphere that is
>   roughly 90 percent nitrogen and 7 percent methane. (Interestingly, as
>   radically different as Titan's atmosphere is to our own, it is still
>   worlds closer in composition and pressure to Earth's nitrogen-rich air
>   than are the CO2-dominant atmospheres of either Mars or Venus.)
>
> Saturn makes Titan's gases come out; Titan's size ensures some of them
>   stick around in an atmosphere. Jupiter's moon Io, being so close to
>   its humungous neighbor, has plenty of volcanic activity, but the
>   moon's mass is too small to wield the kind of gravity needed to
>   maintain a hold on the gases that gush out of its insides.

Answer (score 0):

While Europa (and Ganymede and Callisto) are indeed not too different in size from Titan, they are too close to the Sun for anything more than [a thin atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter#Exploration) to form.

Jupiter and its moons are far away enough from the Sun to allow for water to condensate and thus form icy moons. At ~5 A.U. there is however still too much sunlight for other volatiles, like the ones found in Titan's atmosphere at 9 to 10 AU to condense.

Titan being further away and thus colder, allowed a surface consisting of mostly water ice and ammonia ice. The ammonia ice reacted over time through photolysis or possibly from internal heat and N2 gas was released, forming an atmosphere.

[This book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319934754) on the bodies in our solar system that have a (subsurface) ocean has a chapter on Titan and its atmosphere.

A final determining factor for the presence of an atmosphere is something you allude to in your question, which is the size, or more precisely, the mass of the moon. You of course need a certain amount of gravity in order to keep all the gases that would form your potential atmosphere from flying off into space.

Comment: How are Jupiters moons too close to the sun? That's a nonsense reason, just in order to give one. Nitrogen in Titan's atmosphere would easily condense at Saturns distances.

Comment: The source I relied on states that the Nitrogen frost line is located roughly at Saturn's orbit. It also notes that while ammonia and methane also exist on the surface of bodies such as ganymede, they are trapped in more complex molecular structures. [See this page of the book](https://books.google.de/books?id=71RnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=nitrogen+frost+line&source=bl&ots=R2hONuH3Sg&sig=ACfU3U3pdXfOQ0-E8lQyGqA_2WvnuQlF7Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyt6rGj43mAhXSGewKHX8FBGUQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=nitrogen%20frost%20line&f=false)

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I'm far from an expert on atmospheric sciences so I'd be more than happy to change (or delete, if it turns out it's actual nonsense) my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderVandenberghe in Stack Exchange we should not post answers that we feel could be "actual nonsense". It would be better if you converted this to one or more comments then deleted the answer post if you suspect that it might not be correct.

Comment: @uhoh I don't think it's "actual nonsense" but if AtmosphericPrisonEscape would show me why he thinks it's nonsense I'd be more than happy to do so. So far I have a source stating what I mention in the answer and a comment saying it's nonsense and thus no reason to believe that my statements were wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderVandenberghe okay in that case I've made a small edit and reversed my vote.